# What does '/* generated by server */ means in mysql-bin replication logs?

Tags: mysql

A table has disappeared from our database. We believe that we have been hacked. Looking at the replication log we see :

```
DROP TABLE `c...` /* generated by server */
```

What does the the /*generated by server */ means ? Does it tell us anything about the way we have been hacked ?

Also at the end of each row in the replication log, there is a series of non alphanumeric caracters. Is there a way to decode them ? Does it provide any additional information about the query ?

Comment: No, you cannot conclude from that binary/replication log entry if you have been hacked. It just means someone entered that command (either directly or indirectly e.g. if a temporary table is auto-dropped). You can try to look in general and/or error log for loginattamps (e.g. if someone trying to guess a password) and in the logs of your os or try to guess from the replication log what else was going on at that time. The replication log should be self-explainatory, so I don't know which non alphanumeric characters you mean, maybe post them.

Comment: @Solarflare Here is an example of non-alpha numeric caracters: update administrator set err_lgn=0, lst_lgn='2016-04-28 14:51:45' where ema='_____' ÖXìa"WDÜïl∑(ºü°/@std!!  or COMMITI{-Ua"WDÜïkm$∫ü°/@std!!

Comment: Are you using `mysqlbinlog` or do you open the files in `vi`?

Comment: @solarflare, I am using mysql-binlog and I edit it with TextEdit on Mac OS. With regards to the Hack, looking at the various log, we understood it came from PHPMyAdmin. We made a few changes so that it can't happen again

Comment: I met exactly the same problem, also confused with "generated by server".